# Regex - moving matched text to earlier in line

Tags: php, regex, textmate2

I have been using regex (in textmate's find & replace tool) to reformat a table of values I've received into a PHP array.

I've got most of the way there - but struggling with the final change.

The current status:

```
$subSectors[1] = 'Crop & Animal Production, Hunting & Related Service Activities'; [1]
$subSectors[2] = 'Forestry & Logging'; [1]
```

I'm looking to batch replace (100s of lines) so that the final characters [\d{0-3}] move to be the main array key.

So the above two lines would become:

```
$subSectors[1][1] = 'Crop & Animal Production, Hunting & Related Service Activities';
$subSectors[1][2] = 'Forestry & Logging';
```

The end of line bracketed values can be 1-3 digits in length.

I can match the bracketed values using:

```
\[\d{0,3}]$
```

But at a loss of how to structure the replacement string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way is to capture `( )` each group separate and then do your replacement.

```
Find: ^(\$\w+)(\[\d+\].*?)\s*(\[\d{0,3}\])$
Replace: $1$3$2
```

[**Live Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/gP4bC3)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to move parts to other parts of the string then you have to extend your pattern to encompass all affected parts of the string, not just the match, i.e. the [1] part.

So, something like:

Match:

```
^(\$\w+\[\d+\])([\s\S]+?)(\[\d{0,3}\])(?=\r|$)
```

Replace:

```
$1$3$2
```

Comment: Thanks so much - this got me really close, it actually matched the entire list but I was able to tweak it to purpose.

Comment: Yeah that was my fear. In PHP or JS you could apply the multiline flag that made it match to the end of each line, but in textmate I'm not sure if that's an option. Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex's are fancy and lovely, and I'm sure it works just fine.

If you're already using TextMate there's a better way.

I made a video for how one would do this using TextMate's [multiple carets](http://blog.macromates.com/2011/multiple-carets/) feature, which is so damn lovely I don't mind evangelising about it.

[Video via screencast.com](http://screencast.com/t/ffQPaGTRL)

What I'm doing in the video is;

- Make a column selection across the lines you like. In the video I click on the first line, then press option + shift and click on the last line. Shift selects between the carets, option makes the selection a column (rather than selecting the block of text).
- Press an arrow key to the left or the right to clear the selection, and result in carets instead.
- Press Command + Right to move all the carets to the end of their respective lines.
- Press Shift + Option + Left two times. You can see that TextMate makes a different selection depending on what you are selecting. Shift selects, option moves the caret in a context sensitive way.
- Command + X to cut the bracketed numbers. Textmate is going to remember the order you copied them.
- Command Left to move back to the beginning of the line, this also re-aligns the carets.
- Option + Right until you're in position, paste. Textmate replaces what you just cut at every caret.

How is it better than a regex?

- It is actually fewer keystrokes (9) than the regexs on this question (53 or 44 respectively, counting the replace)
- You don't need to understand regexs to do it
- You don't need the find window

How is it worse?

- It is not as reusable, so if you need to do this across 5+ files or if you (might) need it in a script, build the regex.