# Regex correctly recognise SKU in title given some specific rules

Tags: php, regex

I have a bunch of product titles, from which I need to extract the SKU that's within them.

So take the following titles as an example:

- 258 Game of Thrones
- E457 Pokemon
- 293A Wool Bed cover
- 572 C Steel frame whatever

So in the above examples, the SKUs are `258`, `E457`, `293A` and `572 C` respectively.

Generally, the SKU is either all numbers (mainly 3 or 4 characters long), or letter E followed again by 3-4 numbers, or a 3-4 digit number, followed by a single letter, or by a single space and a single letter.

So I came up with this pattern that seems to work well in identifying all of the above cases: `/^E?\d+ ?.?/`

https://regex101.com/r/I7kkDP/2

Then, there are some totally messed up titles, which have the SKU somewhere in the middle... From what I saw, these cases are rare, and when they happen it's only numbers, so no starting E, or ending single letter. Two examples of this are the following:

- Decorative pillow / Set with bed covers `2456` 55Χ55cm
- Pillow `207` 45 Χ 65 cm

Fortunately, the SKU in these rare cases is the first whole number that's met in the title.

So, what I need is `preg_replace` to fix the above totally messed up titles, so that then my pattern can correctly extract the SKU.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Is there a minimum number of digits in each SKU? It looks like 3 but needs clarifying

Comment: A 3-digit number is the minimum SKU from what I can observe. Then, like I said, there are `E9999` (3 or 4 numbers), `9999 A` (3 or 4 numbers), and `9999A` (3 or 4 numbers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use word-boundaries (`\b`) to delineate the SKU from any other characters, then just check for your defining characters.

The boundaries will ensure you don't falsely match `258 G` from `258 Game of Thrones`.

```php
$rx = '/\bE?\d{3,}( ?[A-Z])?\b/';
if (preg_match($rx, $title, $matches)) {
    [ $sku ] = $matches;
}
```

https://3v4l.org/rCEqD

Comment: That is brilliant Phil, and it's exactly what I needed! There is only one thing left, which is some preg_replace to fix the title, that is, bring the recognised SKU at the beginning, and then the rest of the title (after taking out the SKU part that was moved).

Comment: @FayeD. check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24173370/283366)

Comment: Phil I just noticed this: The `\d{3,}` part of the pattern works well for the given examples, but if the dimension part of the title, is a 3-digit number, like 150 x 150 cm it identifies that as part of the SKU. Take for example this: https://regex101.com/r/fF4GYy/1 where it mis-identifies the SKU for the 5th title. Ideally, it shouldn't use a minimum digit pattern. It should detect the first whole number, so Something 245 150 x 150 cm should return 245 as the SKU.

Comment: @FayeD. you said the SKU was the first whole number so it shouldn't matter if any other numbers follow. Make use of the `$limit` parameter for `preg_replace()` if you're getting multiple matches

Comment: But it matters in your solution unfortunately. Try this title for example: `Decorative pillow / Set with bed covers 256 155Χ55cm`

Comment: @FayeD. that exact example is in the 3v4l.org link I provided

Comment: My bad! Indeed in your code it works fine! However, here https://regex101.com/r/mmpelA/1 it seems to malfunction! Could you figure out why? What did I miss to transfer?

Comment: There you are finding all matches. `preg_match()` only find the first. If you're using `preg_replace()`, use the `$limit` parameter to avoid multiple replacements

Answer (score 2):

I can answer the RegEx pattern part: `(E?\d{3,4} ?[A-Z]?(?=\s))`, tested at https://regex101.com with the following text block:

```
258 Game of Thrones E457 Pokemon
293A Wool Bed cover 572 C Steel frame whatever
258 Game of Thrones
E457 Pokemon
293A Wool Bed cover
572 C Steel frame whatever
Decorative pillow / Set with bed covers 2456 55Χ55cm
Pillow 207 45 Χ 65 cm
```